# Remove first field of JSON string with Go

Tags: json, go

With an http GET request I'm importing a JSON response into a string. I want to add the JSON string into a struct array with json.Unmarshal. This works only when I remove at the beginning the fields data & categoryGroups. They are not part of my strucs. So by removing {"data":{"categoryGroups": at the beginning and }} at the end.

This can be done with a strings.Replace, but I'm wondering if there is a neater solution?

```
{"data":{"categoryGroups":[{"name":"...."}]}]}}
```

Comment: In my opinion the best way is to just unmarshal into a matching structure and then ignore the undesired parts. For example: https://play.golang.org/p/tZHtt5hq-d3

Comment: Thanks, this is indeed much better. Your code example really helped me!!

Answer (score 1):

Based on suggestions from comments, I reproduced your scenario as follows:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

var data = []byte(`{"data":{"categoryGroups":[{"name":"group1"}]}}`)

type CategoryGroup struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
}

func main() {
    var v struct {
        Data struct {
            CategoryGroups []CategoryGroup `json:"categoryGroups"`
        } `json:"data"`
    }
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &v); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    cgs := v.Data.CategoryGroups
    fmt.Println(cgs)
}
```

Output:

```
[{group1}]
```